# Can't figure out why variable is unassigned or undeclared

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio just threw this warning screen at me:

[image]

I know what it means but I can't figure out how to fix it. When I look through the "InitializeComponent()" method everything seems fine. It's a custom control consisting of a Table and a lot of text boxes. The program can still be compiled fine without errors. I have looked around on the internet to find a solution but none of the examples really fit mine and whatever I tried for "hotfixes" didn't really solve anything.

Variables:

```
private BiologiskFamiliePanel sdBiologiskFamiliePanel;
```

InitializeComponent:

```
...
this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.BiologiskFamiliePanel();
...
this.sdGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel); // Where the Error Message put me
...
this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 338);
this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Name = "sdBiologiskFamiliePanel";
this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(329, 272);
this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.TabIndex = 2;
```

Can you spot something that I have obviously missed?

EDIT:

StamDataPanel.Designer.cs

```
using Smart_Journal.Controls;

namespace Smart_Journal.Controls
{
    partial class StamDataPanel
    {
        /// <summary> 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.sdGroupBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.PlejeFamiliePanel();
            this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.BiologiskFamiliePanel();
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.PlejeBarnPanel();
            this.sdMenuStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdGemItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.visToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdVisVederlagItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdVisAlleItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.PlejeFamilieKursusListePanel();
            this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.PlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel();
            this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel = new Smart_Journal.Controls.PlejeFamilieVedlagPanel();
            this.sdGroupBox.SuspendLayout();
            this.sdMenuStrip.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // sdGroupBox
            // 
            this.sdGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel);
            this.sdGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel);
            this.sdGroupBox.Controls.Add(this.sdPlejeBarnPanel);
            this.sdGroupBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 27);
            this.sdGroupBox.Name = "sdGroupBox";
            this.sdGroupBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(644, 610);
            this.sdGroupBox.TabIndex = 0;
            this.sdGroupBox.TabStop = false;
            this.sdGroupBox.Text = "Stamdata";
            // 
            // sdPlejeFamiliePanel
            // 
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.AutoSize = true;
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(337, 19);
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.Name = "sdPlejeFamiliePanel";
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(296, 415);
            this.sdPlejeFamiliePanel.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // sdBiologiskFamiliePanel
            // 
            this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 338);
            this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Name = "sdBiologiskFamiliePanel";
            this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(329, 272);
            this.sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // sdPlejeBarnPanel
            // 
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.AutoSize = true;
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.Bemaerkninger = null;
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 19);
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.Name = "sdPlejeBarnPanel";
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(329, 313);
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.TabIndex = 0;
            this.sdPlejeBarnPanel.TideligereForanstaltninger = null;
            // 
            // sdMenuStrip
            // 
            this.sdMenuStrip.AllowMerge = false;
            this.sdMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem,
            this.visToolStripMenuItem});
            this.sdMenuStrip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.sdMenuStrip.Name = "sdMenuStrip";
            this.sdMenuStrip.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(918, 24);
            this.sdMenuStrip.TabIndex = 3;
            this.sdMenuStrip.Text = "menuStrip1";
            // 
            // filerToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.sdGemItem});
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem.Name = "filerToolStripMenuItem";
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "";
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(41, 20);
            this.filerToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Filer";
            // 
            // sdGemItem
            // 
            this.sdGemItem.Name = "sdGemItem";
            this.sdGemItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "Ctrl + S";
            this.sdGemItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 22);
            this.sdGemItem.Text = "Gem Ændringer";
            this.sdGemItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdGemItem_Click);
            // 
            // visToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this.visToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem,
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem,
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem,
            this.sdVisVederlagItem,
            this.sdVisAlleItem});
            this.visToolStripMenuItem.Name = "visToolStripMenuItem";
            this.visToolStripMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(34, 20);
            this.visToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Vis";
            // 
            // sdVisPlejeboernItem
            // 
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem.Name = "sdVisPlejeboernItem";
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem.ShortcutKeyDisplayString = "";
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 22);
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem.Text = "Andre Plejebørn";
            this.sdVisPlejeboernItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdVisPlejeboernItem_Click);
            // 
            // sdVisBFamilieItem
            // 
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem.Name = "sdVisBFamilieItem";
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 22);
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem.Text = "Biologisk Familie";
            this.sdVisBFamilieItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdVisBFamilieItem_Click);
            // 
            // sdVisKursusListeItem
            // 
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem.Name = "sdVisKursusListeItem";
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 22);
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem.Text = "Kursus Liste";
            this.sdVisKursusListeItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdVisKursusListeItem_Click);
            // 
            // sdVisVederlagItem
            // 
            this.sdVisVederlagItem.Name = "sdVisVederlagItem";
            this.sdVisVederlagItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 22);
            this.sdVisVederlagItem.Text = "Vederlag";
            this.sdVisVederlagItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdVisVederlagItem_Click);
            // 
            // sdVisAlleItem
            // 
            this.sdVisAlleItem.Name = "sdVisAlleItem";
            this.sdVisAlleItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(163, 22);
            this.sdVisAlleItem.Text = "Vis Alle";
            this.sdVisAlleItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.sdVisAlleItem_Click);
            // 
            // sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel
            // 
            this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(652, 27);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel.Name = "sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel";
            this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(262, 195);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel
            // 
            this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(653, 387);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel.Name = "sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel";
            this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(262, 210);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel
            // 
            this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(652, 228);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel.Name = "sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel";
            this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(262, 156);
            this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // StamDataPanel
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(this.sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sdGroupBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.sdMenuStrip);
            this.Name = "StamDataPanel";
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(918, 640);
            this.sdGroupBox.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.sdGroupBox.PerformLayout();
            this.sdMenuStrip.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.sdMenuStrip.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox sdGroupBox;
        private BiologiskFamiliePanel sdBiologiskFamiliePanel;
        private PlejeBarnPanel sdPlejeBarnPanel;
        private PlejeFamilieVedlagPanel sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip sdMenuStrip;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem visToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdVisPlejeboernItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdVisBFamilieItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdVisKursusListeItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdVisVederlagItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdVisAlleItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem filerToolStripMenuItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem sdGemItem;
        private PlejeFamiliePanel sdPlejeFamiliePanel;
        private Controls.PlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel;
        private PlejeFamilieKursusListePanel sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel;
    }
}
```

StamDataPanel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Smart_Journal.Controls;
using Smart_Journal.Familie;

namespace Smart_Journal.Controls
{
    public partial class StamDataPanel : UserControl
    {
        public StamDataPanel(PlejeBarn p)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public StamDataPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void sdGemItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Utility.GemStamdata(this);
        }

        private void sdVisPlejeboernItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel
        }

        private void sdVisBFamilieItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //sdBiologiskFamiliePanel.EnableFields(true);
        }

        private void sdVisKursusListeItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void sdVisVederlagItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void sdVisAlleItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public PlejeBarnPanel PlejeBarnPanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdPlejeBarnPanel;
        }

        public PlejeFamiliePanel PlejeFamiliePanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdPlejeFamiliePanel;
        }

        public PlejeFamilieVedlagPanel PlejeFamilieVedlagPanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdPlejeFamilieVedlagPanel;
        }

        public PlejeFamilieKursusListePanel PlejeFamilieKursusListePanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdPlejeFamilieKursusListePanel;
        }

        public PlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel PlejeFamilieAndreBornPanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdPlejeFamilieAndreBornPanel;
        }

        public BiologiskFamiliePanel BiologiskFamiliePanelObjekt()
        {
            return sdBiologiskFamiliePanel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any time I've had these unexplained errors when using WinForms and the designer, a "Microsoft fix" has always cleared it up. Closing and re-opening Visual Studio, or deleting and re-adding the variable. Maybe deleting the .suo or .csproj.user files to clear up whatever may be stuck.

Comment: Is `this.sdGroupBox` null?

Comment: I have now added all of the code from that class.

Comment: try the rebuild all command after a visual studio restart

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: We need the rest of the partial class, I think. Also, a question: are you deriving from this class, or are you trying to use it directly?

Comment: Using it Directly. I will add the rest of the partial class.

Answer (score 0):

I presume, you might have some logic or initializing code within the `BiologiskFamiliePanel` constructor, which is failing at designer/load. Please check all the logic, which you might have it within the `BiologiskFamiliePanel` construction phase.

Comment: I had one additional constructor which took an argument but still used the same method. But even after I commented that out I still got the error. Otherwise I don't have any other initialization logic.

Comment: @Vipar, "I had one additional constructor which took an argument but still used the same method". I am confused. Why don't you post that code

Comment: I have posted the rest of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue is.

In my BiologiskFamiliePanel.cs I have a function called "VisData()". It basically shows data as it is initially not visible.

However the constructor called this method by calling "EnableField()" and then the issue appears because you can't show data you don't have.